# Flask + Gunicon + Nginx + Supervisor Non Default Port Numbers

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have 2 Flask Apps that are required to be cohosted. Here's what I am trying to achieve:

- App 1, `/home/myuser/proj1/app1`, port 9001, External URL http://example.com/path1
- App 2, `/home/myuser/proj2/app2`, port 9002, External URL http://example.com/path2

I am using Gunicorn to run App 1 (very similar for App 2). There is Nginx in front and we use Supervisor to manage the various components.

Both projects have their own virtualenv `venv` with required package installed.
The configuration file I use to start this application via Supervisor.

```
[program:app1]
command = /home/myuser/proj1/app1/venv/bin/python /home/myuser/proj1/app1/venv/bin/gunicorn app1:app

environment =
    CONFIG_1 = /home/myuser/proj1/conf/config_1.cfg,
    CONFIG_2 = /home/myuser/proj1/conf/config_2.cfg
directory = /home/myuser/proj1/app1
user = myuser
stderr_logfile = /var/log/app1/stderr.log
stdout_logfile = /var/log/app1/stdout.log
```

I have tried

```
command = /home/myuser/proj1/app1/venv/bin/python /home/myuser/proj1/app1/venv/bin/gunicorn app1:app -b localhost:9001
```

but it defaults to port 8000.

Could someone please suggest how I can get `app1` to run on port 9001?

Thanks in advance.

Information that might help.

- OS : Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Python : 2.7.10 (2.7.11 inside `venv`)
- Gunicorn : 17.5
- Flask : 0.10.1

Comment: Are you not by change specifying the port in the configuration files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the command should be:

```
command = /home/myuser/proj1/app1/venv/bin/gunicorn app1:app -b localhost:9001
```

---

By the way, you may take a look at the documentation: [Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/patterns/appdispatch/), combining multiple flask applications on the WSGI level. In your case, maybe `DispatcherMiddleware` would be good:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from app1 import app as path_one
from app2 import app as path_two

application = DispatcherMiddleware(path_one, {
    '/path2': path_two
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind it on `0.0.0.0:9001` which means that it will listen on every available interface.